# C# Using base or this in inherited get

Tags: c#, inheritance, this

I am having trouble understanding the proper use of `base` and `this` within an inherited `get` method. I have an interface `IMatchModel`:

```
public interface IMatchModel
{
    int TypeId { get; }
    DateTime DataDate { get; set; }
    string TypeName { get; set; }
}
```

And a base model class `TradeModel`:

```
public class TradeModel
{
    public long TradeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataDate { get; set; }
    public string TradeName { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a class that inherits from `TradeModel` and implements `IMatchModel`. I am currently using the following method:

```
public class TradeMatchModel : TradeModel, IMatchModel
{
    public int TypeId { get { return 1; } }
    public string TypeName 
    {
        get
        {
            return base.TradeName;
        }

        set
        {
            base.TradeName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The `TradeModel` class is used within a function that operates on all of its attributes. `IMatchModel` is used in a function that only needs the attributes contained in the interface. The code works properly, but I still feel like I don't quite understand if it is best to be using `base` over `this`. Is the use of `base` in this context incorrect?

Comment: A simple way to think about this is, `base` will execute the code that's on the parent class, whilst `this` will execute the code that's on the current class. This is helpful to keep in mind if you override any methods or decide to hide the parent class method (by `new`-ing it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time you need to use `base` is when you are inside a overridden virtual method and you need to call the base implementation of the method you are currently overriding. All other times you can use `this.`.

Also `this.` is generally not needed unless you have a name conflict between a field or property in the class and a name of a variable or a parameter. 99% of the time you can just leave off the `this.` and do `return TradeName;`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Lets say I cast a variable of type `TradeModel` to a `TradeMatchModel` then pass it to a function that takes `IMatchModel` as a parameter. When I access the attribute that is calling the `base` attribute, am I accessing the original variable's value? If I were not using `base` would it be referencing the same value?